# Bootbox callback function not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootbox

I am trying to use Bootbox within an Angular2 application.  I have the following code:

```
  bootbox.confirm({
      message: "Are you sure you want to complete this action?",
      buttons: {
          confirm: {label: 'Yes', className: 'btn-success'},
          cancel: {label: 'No', className: 'btn-danger'}
      },
      callback: function (result: any) {
          console.log('Response equals: ' + result);
      }
  });
```

The confirm box displays correctly when called and when clicking on either the "yes" or "no" button the confirm box disappears as it should.  However, the callback function is not firing because I'm not getting the console message.

This is my first attempt trying to inject Bootbox into an application so I'm not sure why the callback function is not being called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with function(result) remove ':any'.

```
bootbox.confirm({
    message: "This is a confirm with custom button text and color! Do you like it?",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Yes',
            className: 'btn-success'
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'No',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
    }
});
```

http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#bb-confirm-dialog. Call back takes only one argument that is result.

Comment: Yes I have tried that way as well and it does not work either.  I still see the same behavior...everything works as expected except for the callback function firing.

Comment: try bootbox.confirm("This is the default confirm!", function(result){ console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result); }); the basic example. if this way callback isn't called then issue is not with callback. some other action might be preventing it from calling the callback.

Comment: I was able to resolve this problem which was actually caused by how I was calling the method inside my typescript file.  I'm still facing an issue with the following:  I'm trying to call a another function inside my typescript file inside the callback and I'm getting a function not defined error callback: function (result) {this.sendMessage(type, response);